# Getting to grips with JQuery

Tags: jquery, each

I want to do "something like this" when a document loads:

```
$(':input:visible').each(function(i){
                                  
    if($(this.getAttribute('required')!=null)) { $(this).css({ 'border-color':'#800000' }); }                               
                                  
});
```

So in simple terms I have:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(':input:visible').each(function(i){
    if($(this.getAttribute('required')!=null))
    { $(this).css({ 'border-color':'#800000' }); }  
    });
    });
```

Is there any reason why it doesn't work?

Comment: AHHH ... found something out so this is an edit - please. The code "does work" but only if on the actual page, the page the form is on is loaded via JQuery into an empty div.  Is there a away round that?

Comment: @Russell Could you clarify how the content is added? It's probably just a case of running your code after you've added the content.

Comment: Hi andres something like this  - $('#adminwrapinner').load('inc/frm_create.php'); - it is automatically loaded as the page opens

Comment: @lonesomeday - it was "running" after the .load() content code

Comment: Thinking this may be somethiong I need to "alter" as I am using a master page with empty div's and loading content it each of them based on various actions that way I can refresh the div with a setInterval as required without a page load

Comment: @Russell Was it just after it in the code, or after the content had finished loading? AJAX (e.g. `load`) is asynchronous.

Comment: @lonesomeday it was/is like this $('#adminwrapinner').load('inc/frm_create.php'); a couple more loads then the code of this question.  BTW $(this).attr('required') and (this.required) don't work but $(this.getAttribute('required') does? must/ could it be something to do with the .load() not finishing?

Comment: @Russell That's because your if condition will always pass, because anything wrapped in `$()` will pass an if condition.

Comment: @lonesomeday OK think I get that, how/ can do you do it without then?

Comment: @Russell Look in more detail at [`$.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) and in particular at the concept of success handlers.

Comment: @lonesomeday Thanks a real lot - I now have it working on the master page just by using a function - $('#adminwrapinner').load('inc/frm_create.php', function() { do the thing in here }); May not be the best/cleanest but it works thanks a "milliom"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line

```
if($(this.getAttribute('required')!=null)) {
```

Is very peculiar.

You want to use the [`attr`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) function:

```
if ($(this).attr('required') != null) {
```

or, even better and more simply, an object property:

```
if (this.required) {
```

Comment: Hi lonesomeday thanks, but if you check back I have made a comment.  The form(/s) are dynamically loaded into empty divs using .load('..'). Is the code works if on the "form" page but not on the master page.  any way found that?

Answer (score 0):

Use this code it works correctly

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('input:visible').each(function(i){
        if($(this).attr('required') != undefined)
            $(this).css({ 'border-color':'#800000' });  
    });
});
```

Comment: sorry but I can assure you it doesn't unless it is on the page that is loaded into the empty div it doesn't work on the "master" page

Comment: You can call it in .load() callback

Answer (score 0):

try this:

style:

```
input.requiredcss { 'border-color':'#800000'; }
```

JS:

```
$('#adminwrapinner').load('inc/frm_create.php', function(response, status, xhr) {

   var adminwrapinner = this;

   if (status == "success") {

     $(':input:visible:not(.requiredcss)', adminwrapinner).each(function(i){

        if($(this).attr('required')) { 
           $(this).addClass("requiredcss"); 
        } 

     });
   }   
});
```

Comment: Thanks for this, but I think I got there just as you posted it, really sorry you didn't get the "tick", but if you get the chance so that I can understand a bit more - and hopefully others - what is the difference between your function(response, status, xhr) and "my" version which was just function() - as said many thanks and sorry about the "tick"